# How to bound the L-2 norm of the product of two non-square matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, random-matrices

Suppose there are two non-square matrices, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$. Assume that $\Vert A \Vert \leq P$ and $\Vert B \Vert \leq Q$, then how can we find the upper bound of $\Vert AB \Vert$?

Comment: What if you square them up by adding a row/column that consists of zeros and an identity matrix.

Comment: Doesn't one have $$\Vert T_1T_2\Vert \leq \Vert T_1\Vert \Vert T_2\Vert$$ for $T_1$ and $T_2$ some linear operators with the corresponding operator norm.

Comment: As what I know, this inequality only hold for square matrix. @Shashi

Comment: @Tom may I ask you which norm you are using then?